# Where to find any information\tutorials on how to develop games with iOS+Blender 3D (Maya)+Unity( or something else )?

Tags: ios, 3d, unity-game-engine, blender, maya

Want to creat games on iOS, but dont know whats better to use - Blender\Maya and Unity\UDK\Cocos ?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest Unity as it is pretty to easy to use once you get it.

Try this tutorial series for Unity if you want to look in to that.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMWhtKjUr10